# Observable<Array<T>> to Observable<T>

Tags: rxjs, rx-java, reactive

The question is simple: How do I convert from `Observable<Array<T>>` to `Observable<T>`?

I would appreciate if you could write answer with rxJS or RxJava but any other langauge is good.

Comment: What is your goal? Emitting every element in the array as a separate event?

Comment: think flatmap is appropriate

Comment: there should be a `flatMapIterable` that will do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Java, `Observable.from()` is what you want:

```
Observable<List<String>> listObservable = Observable.just(Arrays.asList("why", "hello", "there"));

listObservable.flatMap(Observable::from)
              .subscribe(str -> System.out.print(str + "-"),
                         throwable -> {});
```

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of ways to tackle your problem depending on your desired result.  Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/txekjufm/):

```
console.clear();

var x = Rx.Observable.of([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]);

x.subscribe(item => {
  console.log('Without flatMap: ' + JSON.stringify(item));
  //Without flatMap: [1, 2, 3]
  //Without flatMap: [4, 5, 6]
});

x.flatMap(item => {
    return item;
  }
).subscribe(item => {
  console.log('With flatMap: ' + item);
  //With flatMap: 1
  //With flatMap: 2
  //With flatMap: 3
  //With flatMap: 4
  //With flatMap: 5
  //With flatMap: 6
});

x.reduce((a, b) => {
  return a.concat(b);
}).subscribe(item => {
  console.log('With reduce: ' + JSON.stringify(item));
  //With reduce: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
});

x.scan((a, b) => {
  return a.concat(b);
}).subscribe(item => {
  console.log('With scan: ' + JSON.stringify(item));
  //With scan: [1, 2, 3]
  //With scan: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
});
```